# Problem with number of times a value is shown

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here when I RUN this code its shows china 2 times but when i comment the "remove" func it show only one 'China '.
What could be the problem with this code?

```
def answer_one():
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    energy=pd.read_excel('Energy Indicators.xls')
    energy=energy[16:243]
    energy=energy.drop(['Unnamed: 0','Environmental Indicators: Energy'],axis=1)

    energy.replace('...', np.nan,inplace = True)
    energy.columns=['Country', 'Energy Supply', 'Energy Supply per Capita', '% Renewable']

    energy['Energy Supply'] *= 1000000
    energy['Country'].replace({"Republic of Korea": "South Korea","United States of America": "United States","United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland": "United Kingdom",
    "China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region": "Hong Kong"},inplace = True)


    def remove(x):
        a=x.split(' (')
        return a[0]
    energy['Country']=energy['Country'].apply(remove)
    def remov(x):
        a=x.split(',')
        return a[0]
    energy['Country']=energy['Country'].apply(remov)
    def spl(x):
        a=''
        for i in range(len(x)):
            if x[i].isdigit():
                break
            else:
                a=a+x[i]
        return a
    energy['Country']=energy['Country'].apply(spl)
    GDP=pd.read_csv('world_bank.csv',skiprows=4)
    GDP.rename(columns={'Country Name': 'Country'}, inplace=True)
    GDP['Country'].replace({"Korea, Rep.": "South Korea", "Iran, Islamic Rep.": "Iran","Hong Kong SAR, China": "Hong Kong"},inplace=True)


    ScimEn=pd.read_excel('scimagojr-3.xlsx')

    df=pd.merge(pd.merge(energy,GDP,on='Country'),ScimEn,on='Country')
    df.set_index('Country',inplace=True)
    df=df[['Rank', 'Documents', 'Citable documents', 'Citations', 'Self-citations', 'Citations per document', 'H index', 'Energy Supply', 'Energy Supply per Capita', '% Renewable', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015']]
    df = (df.loc[df['Rank']<16])
    df.sort('Rank',inplace=True)
    df=df.loc[df['% Renewable']!=0]
    #energy[energy['Country']=='China']

    return energy[energy['Country']=='China']
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have two values as follows:

```
China (XXXXXXX)
China (YYYYYYY)
```

When you apply your remove function, both of the above strings will return "China". That might be the problem. Before applying the remove function, you can print the names which start with China with the following line:

```
print(energy[energy['Country'].str.startswith("China")])
```